# Translate element location in React Native to CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

I have implemented something similar to Instagram tags in React Native, where a user can place and drag a shape on top of an image. To do this, I'm setting the style dynamically like this:

```
  dynamicStyle(data) {
    const left = (SCREEN_WIDTH * data.locationX) / 100;
    const top = (SCREEN_HEIGHT * data.locationY) / 100;
    return {
      position: 'absolute',
      top,
      left: left - 22,
      justifyContent: 'center',
    };
  }
```

`data.locationX` and `data.locationY` refer to the coordinates where a user moved the object to. This works well in React Native.

I now want to display those same objects on top of the same image in a web version of the app. Using the same co-ordinates doesn't work. I assume this is because React Native uses density-independant pixels, and CSS doesn't.

Here's a diagram to represent the position in React Native (correct) and React web (incorrect):
[image: Correct and incorrect placement]

How can I use the same relative screen co-ordinates in a responsive webview?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to put a unit after the values for `top` and `left`. I think you want percent (`%`).

Comment: The above code works great in React Native, without any unit. Using `px` or `%` in CSS with the same values doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah that's fine in React Native where size values don't have explicit units, but in CSS you need to use a unit for the `top` and `left` properties. However CSS in JS seems to accept values without units for this. So what do you mean by "it doesn't work"?

Comment: Sorry - I should've clarified. The objects appear above the image, and they're positioned correctly in relation to one another, but they're in the wrong place in relation to the image. I've added an image to my original question to illustrate this.